# Writing unittest for config reader Python unittest library

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am new to unittest library in Python. I have a sample code below where I want to test if the variables are populating the values correctly.
To begin with should I replace the call to config reader? I was thinking of supplying a config text instead of reading from the location to isolate. How can I achieve this? Some starter points could help.

Sample code:

```
import sys
import os.path
from configparser import ConfigParser

templates=""
testfile=""
runbook=""

def init():
   global templates
   global testfile
   global runbook

   if len(sys.argv) > 1:
     currPath = sys.argv[1]
   else: currPath = r"Directory path"
   conf = os.path.join(currPath,"temp.properties")
   config = ConfigParser()
   config.read(conf)

   templates = os.path.join(currPath, config.get("setting", "Templates"))
   testfile = os.path.join(currPath, config.get("setting", "Testfile"))
   runbook = os.path.join(currPath, config.get("setting", "Runbook"))
```

My temp.properties file

```
[setting]
Templates=temp\Templates.xml
Testfile=reports\TestCases.xml
Runbook=reports\Runbook.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by mocking app.ConfigReader.
I mocked the return value of ConfigReader.get to return side_effect of strings in a list.